# In Kotlin, what is the difference between var s: String = "hello" and var s = "hello" as String?

Tags: kotlin

Not clear on what type casting is, but my understanding is that it is similar to type coercion. This tells me that is about assigning type, but what is the difference between these two?

Sometimes I even see var greeting: String = "hello" as String

Comment: `var greeting = "hello" as String` casts "hello", which is a String, to the type String. So this cast is completely unnecessary (and IntelliJ marks it as useless). If you really see that in code, it probably means the developer doesn't really understand what he/she's doing.

Comment: I assumed it was a contrived example done for explanatory purposes.

Comment: You should have chosen "In Kotlin, what is the difference between var s = “hello” as String? and var s: String = “hello”?" as the question... otherwise JB Nizets comment would be the actual answer :-)

Comment: Except you meant `var s = "hello" as String`... then his comment *is* the answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`var s : String  = "hello"` is normal declaration of mutable variable which is value absolutely is string. It will be error if you do others value.
Then 
`Var s = "hello" as String` is casting value of Hello to String then store that value to variable s. I think the difference between both of them are order of execution. In this case you tell the type of data first, but in second case your type data is not clear but casting the value to string even though the result will be same

Answer (score 1):

If you write `var s: String = "hello"` or `var s = "hello"`, the variable has - not surprisingly - the type of `String`.

However, that means you can't store `null` values in that `var`, as the type `String` is not "nullable" in Kotlin. The type that allows both `String`s and `null`is called `String?` in Kotlin.

To let your `var` allow to take `null` values, you can specify the type explicitly with `var s: String? = "hello"`. But you can also cast `"hello"` to be of type `String?` by writing `val s = "hello" as String?`, so that the type inference picks up that new type. In my opinion the last version is unnecessary confusing, and I would avoid it, but to be fair, their are rare situations where casting e.g. `String` to `String?` is convenient, when there is not such a nice way to specify an explicit type as in your example.

Comment: I couldn't find any such `as xxx?`-construct in my whole code-base (except for places where there was an `Any` involved) would be nice to see such a rare example where it is really needed... :-)

Comment: The `as String?` is using the unsafe cast operator, so I can't think of any scenario where it would be preferable over specifying the type explicitly for this particular case of declaring a variable. For example, writing `var s = 500 as String?` will compile but crash at runtime, whereas `var s: String? = 500` would not compile.